# Uncaught TypeError Dotenv Create on updating to Craft CMS 4

Tags: craft3, craft4

Just updated to Craft 4, migrated my `/web` folder over as well as my `/assets` folder and trying to load the index page gives me the following error.

Any help would be great as I can no longer access my `/admin`

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Dotenv\Dotenv::create(): Argument #1 ($repository) must be of type Dotenv\Repository\RepositoryInterface, string given, called in /app/web/index.php on line 15 and defined in /app/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php:83 Stack trace: #0 /app/web/index.php(15): Dotenv\Dotenv::create('/app') #1 {main} thrown in /app/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 83
```

My composer.json looks like the following:

```
{
  "require": {
    "craftcms/cms": "^4.2.0.2",
    "craftcms/feed-me": "5.0.4",
    "craftcms/redactor": "3.0.2",
    "nystudio107/craft-seomatic": "4.0.7",
    "nystudio107/craft-similar": "4.0.0",
    "putyourlightson/craft-blitz": "4.2.1",
    "putyourlightson/craft-sprig": "2.1.0",
    "verbb/image-resizer": "3.0.1",
    "verbb/wishlist": "2.0.0",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.4.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-shell": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
      "craftcms/plugin-installer": true,
      "yiisoft/yii2-composer": true
    },
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform": {
      "php": "8.1.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like your `web/index.php` file was created for an older version of the `vlucas/phpdotenv` library. The error method shows that you're initializing the library in a way that's [compatible with version `^3.0.0`](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/tree/3.6), but in your `composer.json`, you're requiring `^5.4.0`. In this version, the library is initialized in a different way, so you need to adjust your `web/index.php` accordingly.

If you're looking for a good place to start, check out the way the library is initialized in the [current version of the Craft starter project](https://github.com/craftcms/craft/blob/main/bootstrap.php):

```php
// Load dotenv?
if (class_exists(Dotenv\Dotenv::class)) {
    // By default, this will allow .env file values to override environment variables
    // with matching names. Use `createUnsafeImmutable` to disable this.
    Dotenv\Dotenv::createUnsafeMutable(CRAFT_BASE_PATH)->safeLoad();
}
```

You're gonna have the same problem with the `craft` binary used for console commands. I recommend copying the following files from the starter project to your local project:

- `bootstrap.php`
- `craft`
- `web/index.php`